# Angular saving default array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, push

I have this code:

```
$scope.DefaultSidebarLinks = [
{
  "Link":"/home",
  "Title":"Home",
  "Icon":"fa-home"
}
];

$scope.SidebarLinks = $scope.DefaultSidebarLinks;

$scope.addSidebarLink = function(link,title,icon,resetFirst){
var element = {"Link":link,"Title":title,"Icon":icon};
if(resetFirst)
  {
    $scope.SidebarLinks = $scope.DefaultSidebarLinks;
    $scope.SidebarLinks.push(element);
  }
else
  $scope.SidebarLinks.push(element);
}
```

The main problem is that when I push a new element in SidebarLinks, it pushes it also in DefaultSidebarLinks.

What I'm trying to do is to reset the SidebarLinks if asked and push the new given element only in this local variable.

Comment: `$scope.SidebarLinks = $scope.DefaultSidebarLinks` does **not** create a copy; both names reference the exact same array object.

Comment: You can use `angular.copy($scope.DefaultSideBarLink)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wen you assign an array like this :

```
$scope.SidebarLinks = $scope.DefaultSidebarLinks;
```

you are creating two arrays which are same i.e two different names of same array . They are pointing to same memory , so any change in `$scope.SidebarLinks`  will also change the array   `$scope.DefaultSidebarLinks` as these both are same .

If you want deep copy an array you can do it by many ways :

Solution1(Angular way):

```
$scope.SidebarLinks=angular.copy($scope.DefaultSidebarLinks);
```

Solution2 (javascript way):

```
 $scope.SidebarLinks = $scope.DefaultSidebarLinks.slice();
```

Basically, the slice() operation clones the array and returns the reference to the new array.